# How to wrap output in R markdown using pdf_document

Tags: r, latex, pdf-generation, r-markdown, knitr

How do I get this result in which both the source code and the output appear wrapped by a line in R markdown using a pdf_document.

[image]

My yaml is configured as follows:

```
---
title: 'Applied Econometrics using R'
subtitle: 'Federal University of Paraiba'
author: 'Alexandre Loures'
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
documentclass: book
bibliography: [econometrics.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
colorlinks: yes
lot: yes
lof: yes
output:
 html_document:
  theme: united
 pdf_document:
  highlight: tango
description: "A book example for a Chapman & Hall book."
github-repo: yihui/bookdown-crc
graphics: yes
#cover-image: images/cover.jpg
---
```